# Using INDIRECT with an Array Input

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I am attempting to help a student with a really simple formula and am having trouble understanding the context of the solution.

We start with a small list of values in columns **A** & **B** and another list of addresses in column **C** that point to the values in column **A** or **B**:

[image]

The goal is to retrieve the items in column **A** or **B** in the order specified in column **C**.

Her first attempt was to use:

```
=INDIRECT(C1:C5)
```

Since we are using Excel 365, this produced a dynamic spill-down of `#VALUE!` errors.  I explained that this is because the `INDIRECT()` worksheet function cannot accept an array input and if we use a string input like `=INDIRECT("C1:C5")` all we get is the address pointers rather than the values themselves.

I suggested `=IF(ROWS($1:1)<=COUNTA(C:C),INDIRECT(C1),"")` and copying downward **manually**.  She left and returned later to tell me that they found a way to make `INDIRECT()` work with an array input:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT(C1:C5),"<>")
```

which DOES work!  What we don't understand is:

1. Why does enclosing a non-working formula in `SUMIF()` make it work
2. Why `SUMIF()` is returning an array rather than a single value

Any explanations or references will be appreciated.

Comment: It has always returned an array.  I know you have done something akin to `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A:A,{"Sally","George"}))` the `COUNTIF` returns a two item array.  One the count of `Sally` and the other `George` then the `SUMPRODUCT` sums them.  Your SUMIF is no different.  They accept an array as the criteria, just not the range.  SUMIF just sees the first as both the criteria and the sum range when there is no third entry.  As to why it work with SUMIF(s)/COUNTIF(s). I have no idea, but I have used this many times in many answers.  I think even for one of your questions on SuperUser.

Comment: yup: https://superuser.com/questions/1547676/dynamic-spill-down-with-indirect

Comment: What is interesting is that right up to the the sumif returning the array it shows an array of errors if you step through.

Comment: @ScottCraner  The behavior of `SUMIF()` with the `INDIRECT()` inside it is completely different than the behavior  of `SUMIF()` if it refers to an outside range of cells.........I just don't understand it.

Comment: Without digging into the code, neither do I.  But it is a great loop hole that I exploit often.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Thank you.................I'll update this if I get any info.